# XmlReader.Create() The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
_rssSource = @"http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(_rssSource);
```

I have the above code which is throwing the following error at GetResponse():

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri)
```

I have tried to trace what is being requested via fiddler but no requests are showing apart from the request for the page that contains the code. The link work fine through ie/visual studio.

I'm not sure if its something to do with the proxy server/IIS/internet settings.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Your code sample doesn't even show a GetResponse().  It's kinda hard to see what's wrong if the relevant code isn't there.

Comment: Do you think that `XmlReader.Create` is inventing a 403 error? There's a real 403 error coming back from the network, and you just can't see it for some reason. Try fetching the content with plain `WebRequest` or `WebClient`, just as an experiment.

Comment: Code works for me. I just declared `string _rssSource;` and entered your code. I'm able to read the file.

Comment: @David Stratton: `XmlReader.Create(string)` will do the request and get the response automatically if the parameter is a URL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx

Comment: The GetResponse() happens within XmlReader.Create() as you can see from the stack trace. It also work fine for me at home, which is why I think it must be some sort of setup issue.

Comment: If it works at home, and not at work, is it at all possible that there is a web filter on your corporate network that is disallowing access to that feed?  We have one in place at our network to filter out anything other than allowed sites, and I get a 403 forbidden from our filter if we try to access something that's not allowed.  See if you can access the feed via Internet Explorer  (or the browser of choice) - something other than your own code, so that you can see if it's accessible at ALL from that machine... - very similar to what @John Saunders suggested.

Comment: Yep, as I said, it works fine through ie/vs2010. according to fiddler no request is being sent from my machine to be rejected unless it is something fiddler isn't monitoring. eg is iis/.net not using the same proxy settings as internet explorer or something.

Comment: It could be a user setting, then...  Perhaps your personal Domain account has permissions, but the Network Service account for that machine does not.  You might have to set up Impersonation to see if it's user-permissions related.

Answer (score 14):

Try to access the same feed with a browser running on the same machine as your code, to eliminate easy-to-detect issues like required credentials or network limitations.  If your browser can read the feed just fine, then you may need to tweak the request properties.

The default .NET user-agent supplied by XmlReader.Create() might be explicitly forbidden by the RSS service.  An easy way to test for this is to explicitly set your user agent string within a WebClient object, and then call the OpenRead() method on your URL:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "MyRSSReader/1.0");

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(webClient.OpenRead(_rssSource));
```

If your invented user agent string doesn't work, you might try spoofing the string of a [well known](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) Feed Reader or browser.

Comment: That The default .NET user-agent supplied by XmlReader.Create() is interesting . 
Never thought about that did not see to set it . Awesome! You get my vote !